# Converting normal matrix to numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The purpose of this code is to arrange the lines, using the third column as a parameter. If I use normal matrix, the program works just fine, but I need to use numpy, because it's part of a bigger program.

The desired output is : [[2,-2,7],[-1,1,4],[10,7,1]]

```
import numpy as np

y = np.matrix([[-1,1,4],[2,-2,7],[10,7,1]])

c = True

def OrdenaMatriz(y):
    matriz = []
    matriz.append(y[0])
    for a in range(2):
        if y[a,2] < y[a+1,2]:
            matriz.insert(a,y[a+1])
        else:
            matriz.append(y[a+1])
    return matriz

while c == True:
    a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
    if a == y:
        c = False
        print(a)
    y = a
```

The following error is showing:

```
DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed; this will raise an 
error in the future.
  if a == y:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 26, in <module>
    a = OrdenaMatriz(y)
  File "teste.py", line 19, in OrdenaMatriz
    if y[a,2] < y[a+1,2]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: What is your desired output from this code?

Comment: `a` is a list. `y=a` reassigns `y` to that list. It is no longer the `np.matrix` you started with.

Comment: This is the desired output   [[2,-2,7],
                                             [-1,1,4],
                                            [10,7,1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The purpose of this code is to arrange the lines, using the third column as a parameter.":

```
>>> y = y[np.argsort(y[:,-1].T),:]
>>> y 
matrix([[[10,  7,  1],
         [-1,  1,  4],
         [ 2, -2,  7]]])
```

Like this?

Comment: yeah, but from the bigger to smaller.

Comment: Could you explain what this code means? How does it do it? I searched for argsort numpy, but couldn't understand how you did this.

Comment: Sure João: `y[:,-1]` is the transposed last column of data, `T ` is the transpose operator, and  `np.argsort` returns the indices which sort an array from smallest to largest. Putting this together, `np.argsort(y[:,-1].T)` returns the indices which sort the last column from smallest to largest. Then, `y[np.argsort(y[:,-1].T),:]` is just sorting the 2d array rows using these indices.

Comment: To reverse the sort, probably there is a reverse keyword argument in `np.argsort`, or you can sort `-y[:,-1].T`, or you can reverse the index array like `np.argsort(y[:,-1].T)[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain your errors and warning.

```
y = np.matrix([[-1,1,4],[2,-2,7],[10,7,1]])
```

could just as well be

```
y = np.array([[-1,1,4],[2,-2,7],[10,7,1]])
```

You don't, especially as a beginner, need to use `np.matrix`.  `np.array()` produces the regular numpy array object.  Using `np.matrix` is discouraged, since it doesn't add anything special now.

`a = OrdenaMatriz(y)` produces a Python list.  You start with `[]`, and either insert or append values, so the result is still a list.

It's the

```
a == y
```

that produces the `DeprecationWarning`.  It's the result of comparing a list with a numpy array.

Then you `y=a`.  Now `y` is a list, not the original array (or matrix).  So on the next loop, `OrdenaMatriz` is called with a list.  That's when

```
y[a,2] < y[a+1,2]
```

raise the TypeError.  That indexing is ok for array/matrix, but not for list.

So if you stick with this code, or something similar, start with an `np.array()` call, and make sure that `OrdenaMatriz` returns an array, not a list.

Comment: the problem is I can't use np.array, cause my program is giving me a np.matrix. i think i will redo this part than. tnks.

Comment: You can turn a `np.matrix` into a `ndarray` with `y.A` or `np.array(y)`.  But from what I see in your code it shouldn't matter.  `matrix` is just an array with `ndim` fixed at 2.  That difference has nothing to do with your confusion produced by `a` being a list.